# Problem about how solutions to an ode keep the same relation as the function in the ode.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to do this exercise:

Let $A$ be an open and connected set in  $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be two real and continuous functions defined in $A$ so that $F_1(x,y)<F_2(x,y) \forall (x,y)\in A$. Let $\phi_i$ be a solution to the ode $y' = F_i(x,y)$ defined in an interval $I$ for $i=1,2$ and consider $x_0 \in I$. Prove that, if $\phi_1(x_0)<\phi_2(x_0)$, then $\phi_1(x)<\phi_2(x) \forall x \geq x_0, x \in I.$

So, what I have tried is this:

Suppose that there exists $x_1 \geq x_0$ so that $\phi_1(x_1)\geq\phi_2(x_1)$. Let's define $h(x)=\phi_2(x)-\phi_1(x)$. By Lagrange theorem we have that: $0<h(x_0)-h(x_1)=h'(z)(x_0-x_1)$. This implies that $h'(z)$ is negative for $z \in (x_0,x_1)$. Then $h'(z)=F_2(z,\phi_2(z))-F_1(z,\phi_1(z))<0.$

I was hoping to reach a contradiction here. However the fact that $\phi_2(z)$ and $\phi_1(z)$ are not necessarily equal does not let me reach a conclusion.

It would be really helpful if anyone could give me a hint as to how to solve this. Maybe I am not aprroaching the problem in the right way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd think about the situation intuitively. It's definitely not a proof, but I hope it'll give you an idea that can be made into a proof.

Imagine that we're running a race, that the variable $x$ in your question represents time, that $\phi_1(x)$ is my position (on the one-dimensional race track) at time $x$, and that $\phi_2(x)$ is your position at time $x$. Then the inequality $\phi_1(x_0)<\phi_2(x_0)$ mean you're ahead of me at time $x_0$. The differential equations satisfied by $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ and the inequality $F_1(x,y)<F_2(x,y)$ mean that, if we're at the same place ($y$) at the same time ($x$) then you're running faster than I am  at that moment. You want to prove that you always stay ahead of me.

Your attempted proof shows that everything would work out if you were always running faster than I am, but, as you noticed, that need not be the case. We're not given any information comparing our speeds if we're at different locations (your $\phi_1(z)$ and $\phi_2(z)$) at the same time ($z$).

But, considering that I started behind you (at time $x_0$), how could I get ahead of you at a later time? I'd have to pass you at some time, and at that particular moment we'd be at the same location. So at that moment you'd be running faster than I am, which makes it impossible for me to pass you.